# How to get Stripe working the Play Framework and IntelliJ?

Tags: java, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, stripe-payments

I'm creating a website using the Play 2.0. I've been hoping to use Stripe to accept credit cards on the website. However, I keep getting the same error when trying to include the Stripe JAR.

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                       
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: com.stripe#stripe-java;latest: not found ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I've looked all over and I think I have implemented every solution I've found, to no avail. I've imported the JARS as an external library, I've added them to a lib folder at my project root, and I've tried to add it to my app dependencies in my Build.scala file. Still, I get this error.

This error only occurred after I added the StripeException class and now I can't seem to get it to go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you explain what you have done? Remember the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies): if you have an unmanaged dependency (*just a jar*), create a directory called `lib` and drop it there. If you want to include the Stripe library as a managed dependency, add the following line to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.stripe" % "stripe-java" % "1.4.2"
```

It looks like you tried to do just that, but with `latest` as the version number instead of `1.4.2`. As far as i can see, Stripe doesn't provide a "latest" version artifact which always points to the latest version.

Comment: I restarted Play and then it worked. I'm not sure why exactly. I had changed it to what you have before and couldn't get it to work, which is why I was so confused. What you have does indeed work.